# Merging multiple point layers with common fields to create single table in QGIS

Tags: qgis, shapefile, fields-attributes, merge, qgis-modeler

I have seven point shapefiles at the same geographic location with three common fields (`"ID"`, `"name2"`, `"name3"`) and a fourth field, (`"uni_value"`) that is unique to each shapefile.

All seven shapefiles have been produced by a QGIS Graphical Modeler workflow and would like to combine all layers into a single table for export into a PostgreSQL database.

Example tables below:

```
Point Layer 1
    ID | name2 | name3 | unique_value1 
Point Layer 2
    ID | name2 | name3 | unique_value2 
Point Layer 3
    ID | name2 | name3 | unique_value3 
.
.
.

Point Layer 7
    ID | name2 | name3 | uni_value7
```

Final Merged table:

```
ID | name2 | name3 | uni_value1 | uni_value2 | ... | uni_value7
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a possibility using a ["Virtual Layer"](https://docs.qgis.org/latest/en/docs/user_manual/managing_data_source/create_layers.html#creating-virtual-layers) through `Layer > Add Layer > Add/Edit Virtual Layer...`.

Let's assume there are two point layers one called *'points1'* and second called *'points2'*, see image below.

[image: input]

With the following query, it is possible *to combine all layers into a single table*.

```sql
SELECT
    "ID",
    "name2",
    "name3",
    "unique1" AS "unique1",
    NULL AS "unique2",
    geometry
FROM
    "points1"
UNION ALL
SELECT
    "ID",
    "name2",
    "name3",
    NULL AS "unique1",
    "unique2" AS "unique2",
    geometry
FROM
    "points2"
```

The output point layer with its attribute table will look like:

[image: result]

Answer (score 1):

1. Menu Processing > Toolbox > Merge Vector Layers.
2. Field calculator: create a new string (text) field with this expression: `concatenate( to_string(unique_value1), concatenator:=',', group_by:=name2 || name3)`.
3. Menu Processing > Toolbox > Delete duplicate Geometries.

Comment: Thank you for answer, but I was looking to put each unique field value into a seperate field instead of one field separated by commas.

Comment: OK, I see. So based on this solution, this is only possible to it one by one for each layer - which is probably not what you want.